# Would combining raw operator new, placement new and standard delete be legal?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

guys! Out of curiosity – the following code would probably not be legal, would it?

```
T *p = ::operator new(sizeof(T)); // allocate memory for a T
new (p) T; // construct a T into the allocated memory
delete p; //delete the object using the standard delete operator
```

Comment: *Nearly* an exact duplicate of a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6495632/179910) by @Fredoverflow, though there's just enough difference that it's probably worth discussion. On a technicality, it's not allowed as-is (you need a cast on the allocation since `::operator new` returns `void *`) but with that fixed, it's a good question (and I'm not sure it's as cut-and-dried as DeadMG's answer implies either).

Comment: What's the point? If you want a `T*` do `new T;`!

Answer (score 7):

No. You can only `delete` what you get back from `new`- no exceptions.

Comment: `delete` must be paired with `new`, but in this case it is. A placement new is still a new expression.

Answer (score 1):

There's at least one circumstance in which it's clearly undefined: if you've overloaded `operator new` and `operator delete` for `T`, then this will attempt to allocate memory using `::operator new`, but delete it using `T::operator delete`. Unless your `T::operator delete` is purely a wrapper around `::operator delete`, that's going to cause a problem.

Other than that, I think it's probably defined. The standard is very specific about the fact that a `new expression` allocates its memory using an allocation function (§5.3.4/10), which will be `::operator new` as long as you haven't provided a `T::operator new`.

Your placement new expression then initializes the object, just as described for a new expression in the first bullet point of §5.3.4/15.

Then we get to the destruction side. According to $5.3.5/1: "The delete-expression operator destroys a most derived object (1.8) or array created by a new-expression." That requires that you have used a new expression to create the object -- which you have. You've used a placement new, which is one of the possibilities for a new expression, and specified in §5.3.4/1.

The next requirements that apply seem to be: "The operand shall have a pointer type, or a class type having a single conversion function (12.3.2) to a pointer type." Again, your expression meets that as well.

I'm going to quote more requirements, without further comment, except that your code seems to meet all of them (some limit the implementation of a delete expression, not the pointer you can use in one):

- (§5.3.5/2): "In the first alternative (delete object), the value of the operand of delete shall be a pointer to a non-array object or a pointer to a sub-object (1.8) representing a base class of such an object (clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined."
- (§5.3.5/3): "In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined.
- (§5.3.5/4): "In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined."
- (§5.3.5/6): "The delete-expression will invoke the destructor (if any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted."
- (§5.3.5/7): The delete-expression will call a deallocation function (3.7.3.2).

With the initial caveat about `::operator new` vs. `T::operator new`, I think the pointer you're using in the `delete expression` meets all the requirements, so the behavior should be defined.

Having said all that, I certainly *hope* this is purely academic interest -- even though it looks to me like the code does have defined behavior, it's a lousy idea even at very best.

Comment: You only mention the "delete expression". What about `::operator delete`? Since the construction involves manual allocation followed by placement-new, wouldn't a more symmetric destruction sequence be `p->~T();` (destroy), `delete (p) p;` (no-op), `::operator delete(p);` (deallocate)?

Comment: Yes, for symmetry with his allocation, he certainly *could* do that. The question is whether the delete expression is required to be equivalent to that. Other than, possibly, the `delete (p) p;`, I think it is.

Comment: It wouldn't have to be, would it? You're required to delete the same way you acquired, so anything else would just be UB, like deleting a malloced pointer.

Comment: @Kerrek: all the requirements I can find are listed above. I don't see where his code violates any of them. Ergo, the behavior seems to be defined. Deleting a malloced pointer does violate them, so it doesn't seem to be the same at all.

Comment: I have trouble seeing through those clauses :-( But check out the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_new#Default_placement): "it is not possible to destroy the object [constructed with placement-new] using a delete expression, that is how one destroys an object that was constructed via a pointer placement new expression." What do you make of that?

Comment: @Karrek: When figuring out what the C++ standard allows, I trust the C++ standard over some random Wikipedia entry. Lacking a citation to the specific part of the standard that says I'm wrong, I can't see where a Wikipedia entry means much.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of DeadMG's correct assertion, there is no problem with a slight change to your code:

```
unsigned char* addr = new unsigned char[sizeof(MySimpleStructure)];
MySimpleStructure* p = new (addr) MySimpleStructure;
delete [] addr;
```

Since we're `delete`ing `addr` which was returned by `new` there is no issue with this being legal.  Of course, after `addr` is deleted, `p` should not be accessed (its a dangling pointer at that time).  Also note that `MySimpleStructure` as allocated via placement new to `p` will not have its destuctor called.

Comment: You miss the "no exceptions" part of DeadMG's answer.

Comment: @BoP: how is this an exception?

Comment: Agreed.  "You can only delete what you get back from new".  Since you downvoted, kindly explain how the answer breaks that rule.  In fact, if what I posted isn't legal, please show an example using placement new with dynamically allocated memory that is later freed.

Comment: @Chad - You say yourself that the destructor isn't called. How is that correct?

Comment: The "destructor" of addr is called, and given the code snippet above, that is all that can be expected.  Placement new is frequently used in this manner, for example a byte-aligned structure with some arbitrary length binary data immediately following it.  The fact that `MySimpleStructure::~MySimpleStructure` isn't called isn't a problem, as long as the coder that writes this understands that fact.