# Returning a pointer to an array of structures from a function that reads in from a file to populate the structure in each element of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, enums, structure

```cpp
/*
This code results in "signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)"
The code requires that an array of structures be initialized with the returned pointer to an array of type Car from the readCarList() function
**/

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

enum  vehicleColor { blue, red, orange, silver, black, green };

struct Car
{
  string brand, model;
  int mileage, year;
  vehicleColor color; // enum type variable
};

// function declaration
Car *readCarList(string file, int numCars);

int main() 
{
  int numCars = 10;

  string fileName = "cars.txt";

  //cout << "Enter a filename:"
  cout <<"  //calling the function....  " << endl;
  
  //Use readCarList function to initalize dynamic array of structures
  Car * vehicle = readCarList(fileName, numCars);

  printCarList(vehicle, numCars); // Call print car list(structArray, 10)

  delete vehicle; // Delete memory to avoid leak
}

Car *readCarList(string fileName, int numCars) 
{
  cout << "Inside of readCarList function";
  int count = 0; 
  string car_color_temp[6];

  //open file for reading
  ifstream inputFile;
  inputFile.open(fileName);

  Car * totalCars; // Pointer to Car variable
  totalCars = new Car[numCars];//Allocate space for 10 elements 

   // Read in data from file into each
  for (int a = 0; a < numCars; a++)
  {
    inputFile >> totalCars[a].brand;
    inputFile >> totalCars[a].model;
    inputFile >> totalCars[a].mileage;
    inputFile >> car_color_temp[a]; //String array for holding color
    inputFile >> totalCars[a].year;
    
    //Convert value read into string array, into structarray[a].color (ENUM data type)
    if (car_color_temp[a] == "blue")
      totalCars[a].color = blue;
    else if (car_color_temp[a] == "red")
      totalCars[a].color = red;
    else if (car_color_temp[a] == "orange")
      totalCars[a].color = orange;
    else if (car_color_temp[a] == "silver")
      totalCars[a].color = silver;
    else if (car_color_temp[a] == "black")
      totalCars[a].color = black;
    else if (car_color_temp[a] == "green")
      totalCars[a].color = green;
  }
  return totalCars;
}
```

The file is organized one piece of information per line, so each of every 5 lines has the make, model, mileage, color (enum variable) and year, e.g.:

```
Ford
F-150
200456
blue
2014
```

I have read through all course content, this program should result in this output:

[image: program output]

I don't need this problem to be solved for me. I need to learn what I am doing incorrectly. If someone could help me, that'd be great.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You ought to post the actual and expected program outputs in the body of the question; not a link, not an image, not a link to an image, but the actual text copied-and-pasted into the question. And pare the code down to the simplest example that produces output other than what is expected. (Along the way, you're very likely to discover the bug yourself.)

Comment: My guess is you put your data file in the wrong folder. And your code has no error checking at all. It attempts to read data for 10 cars regardless if the file is read or not or if there is lines worth of data.

Comment: I find myself wondering how you can know the number of cars in the file before reading the file.

Comment: The bug is here `delete vehicle; ` it should be `delete [] vehicle;` since you allocated with `new Car[];` you delete what you new and delete [] what you new[]

Comment: Warning: `>>` reads exactly one whitespace-delimited token from the input stream, so as soon as you find yourself with a car name like "Karmann Ghia", you're up a creek. "Karmann" is read into `totalCars[a].model` leaving "Ghia" for `totalCars[a].mileage`. "Ghia' doesn't convert to an `int` all that well, and since the read is not tested for success, the program breaks. Since each piece of information is on a line and presumable takes up that whole line, consider using `std::getline`.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495632/mixing-operator-new-and-placement-new-with-ordinary-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495632/mixing-operator-new-and-placement-new-with-ordinary-delete)

Comment: car_color_temp is an array of 6, but you use 10 of them. This will be an out of bounds access. This is wrong & could produce a segfault. It appears, though, that your code only really needs one of them as these values are not kept around.

Comment: Any reason why you are using a `new[]`'d pointer at all, instead of using `std::vector`? Is this a homework assignment that doesn't let you use `vector` yet?